# Better way to output days of the week between other functions

Tags: c++

I am new to c++.  What is a better way to do this?  I am trying to output the days of the week and also put functions between the days. I want to output Monday separate from outputting the other days of the week.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;



void day(char* name[]);



    int main()
    {


    char* dayNames[] =
        { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",  
        "Sunday"};

    day(dayNames);
    day(dayNames + 1);
    day(dayNames + 2);
    day(dayNames + 3);
    day(dayNames + 4);
    day(dayNames + 5);
    day(dayNames + 6);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
void day(char* name[])
{

    int n = 0;
    if (n >=0 && n <= 6)
        {
            cout << "Today is " << name[n] << "." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish, but instead of calling the `day` function with an array of day names, why not have the `day` function contain the array and just pass the day-number into the function? That way the use of `n` in the function will make sense.

```
void day(int);

int main()
{

    day(-1);
    day(0);
    day(3);
    day(7);
}

void day(int n)
{
    const char *day_names[] = {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
    };

    if (n >= 0 && n < 7)
        cout << "Today is " << day_names[n] << "." << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: And making that array a global static one.. why not?

Comment: `sizeof(day_names)` != 7. It equals `sizeof(char*) * 7`, which for me is 56, and for others may also be 28.

Comment: Good work. As you probably already know, you could alternatively have `sizeof(day_names) / sizeof(*day_names);`.

Comment: @AusCBloke I guess that's what I tried to do. My excuse is that I just woke up. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do, but from the multiple calls to `day()`  I'm guessing that you're trying to call a function that, when passed a number representing the index of the day of the week, prints the day associated with that index.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
// monday = day 1, sunday = day 7
void printDay(unsigned day)
{
   static char *dayNames[] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                               "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

   if (day >=1 && day <= 7)
      cout << "Today is " << dayNames[n - 1] << "." << endl;
}
```

`printDay(1)` will print "Today is Monday."

`printDay(7)` will print "Today is Sunday."